# How to do Client server communication in Android?

Tags: android

I want to send and receive information between Emulators in Android.i am using two systems and i have installed android in both the systems and i have to consider one emulator as server and another as client.Now i want to send data from one to another.Anyone knows regrading this please help me with some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Java Socket.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of information do you want to send between the emulators?

You can transmit SMS messages, or simulate phone calls, from one emulator to another using the target emulator's console port number as the number to dial. The Android Developer Site describes the process in more detail under "[Sending a Voice Call or SMS to Another Emulator Instance](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#calling)"

If you want to transmit data, unfortunately Android doesn't currently provide any P2P or Instant Messaging APIs, so there's no generic technique available through the SDK you can use.

Your best alternative is to create your own server-based solution (or your own P2P API, though that might be a little more complicated).